# how to get the value of child nodes in firebase (swift), and display it in a label on a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

this is my firebase structure

Users:

simple login 1:

- Name : mike
- age : 24
- location : USA

i am trying to get the info of currently logged in user and display it on a label in view controller.

i have wrote the following code in the view did load :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

    println(snapshot.value["users\(self.ref.authData.uid)/age"] as? String)

    })
```

but when i run my app it prints "nil" in the console.what lines of code should i write to get info of child nodes? once i get it then i can easily set my labels according to it. please help me i am new to swift and firebase.

***MORE***

Here's how i created Ref :

```
var ref = Firebase(url: "https://chatty93.firebaseio.com/")

var userId = authData.uid

let newUser = [                       
  "name": self.Name.text,
  "location" : "",
  "age"      : "",
]

self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
    .childByAppendingPath(authData.uid)
    .setValue(newUser)
```

the name is provided by the logged in user on this view controller and age and location are provided by the logged in user on another view controller.. here is what i coded on the other view controller :

```
var age: Void  = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/age").setValue(AgeTextField.text)
var location: Void  = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/location").setValue(LocationTextField.text)
var About : Void = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/about").setValue(AboutTextField.text)
```

now on another view controller i just want this age location and name to be taken from firebase and displayed on labels but i just can't figure out how to do it .. i tried the observe event of single type but it is giving me nil.. please help me with this! thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide how you're creating the ref?

Comment: @DavidEast i have mentioned in the post above how i created ref .. please have a look at the code and help me out

Comment: @Kamran Ahmend Khan's answer looks right. Look at the URL of the data you're trying to access. Make sure the path you're programatically creating matches that path. If not, the data will be nil at that location.

Comment: @DavidEast plz help me how should i edit the url.? if i am trying to users/authdata.uid/age.. what should i change in the url?

Comment: this problem is solved .. the value of age is pritning in the console but when i try to set it to a label ..  this is what i coded: 

" self.AgeLbl.text = snapshot.value["age"] as? String "

 but when the view loads the AgeLabel shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
.childByAppendingPath(authData.uid)
.childByAppendingPath("age")
.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        println(snapshot.value)


    })
```

Comment: him let me try i will let u know :)

Comment: i tried but it is not printing any thing the console stays blank! :(

Comment: Please consider adding some more detail to your code.

Comment: could you be more precise? what exactly should i add ? @iosDev82

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi The comment is intended for Kamran Ahmed. Currently the answer only has code with no explanation of what it does.

Comment: @iosDev82 can u help?

Comment: Kami you beauty ! it worked thanks :)  @Kamran Ahmed Khan

Comment: it printed the value in the console...now how do i display it on a label ? 
i coded : " self.AgeLbl.text = snapshot.value["age"] as? String "

but when the view loads the AgeLabel shows nothing

Comment: Using this code with some changes i am now able to change the value of labels in the view controller ! Problem Solved!

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
    let enumerator = snapshot.children
    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
       println(rest.value)     
    }
})